# How can I show my modal outside my sidenav? I'm using :host. Angular

Tags: angular

I have a :host with hostlistener() in my navmenu-component.ts. I made this so I can have a sidemenu which slides out of my sidenavbar when i press a button.

I want to call a modal to edit something. So I have made a modal in the navmenu-component.html. Whenever I call my modal it shows in the collapsable menu.

I don't know how I can make this show outside my collapsable menu, I think it has something to do with my :host but i can't seem to find out what to do.

here are my components

this is my navmenu-component.html

```
    <div  class="environmentHolder w100" (click)="openClose()">
        <div class="dropdown-env" >
            <div class="header">
                <p>{{textDDL}}<fa-icon [icon]="arrow"></fa-icon></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="environments.length == 0; else divFilled">
            <div class="dropdown-env-content slidedown" #ddl >
                <p (click)='goToEnv()'>Create New Environment <fa-icon [icon]="plus"></fa-icon></p>
                <h6>0/2</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ng-template #divFilled>
            <div class="dropdown-env-content slidedown1env" #ddl *ngFor="let item of environments"> 
    
                <input type="image" id="dropbtn" src="assets/menu.png" style="width: 30px; height: 20px; border: none; transform: rotate(90deg);"  aria-controls="drop1" class="button dropdown" (click)="openMenu()"/><br>
                <ul id="drop1" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown" style="display: none; margin-right: 15px;">
                    <li><a (click)="goToEnvUpdate(item.id)" #editButton >Edit</a></li>
                    <li><a #deleteButton >Delete</a></li>
                </ul>
    
                <p [ngClass]="isVisible" *ngFor="let env of environments" (click)="getEnvironment(env.id)" >{{env.name}}</p>
                <div *ngIf="environments.length &lt; 2">
                    <p (click)='goToEnv()' [ngClass]="isVisible">Create New Environment <fa-icon [icon]="plus"></fa-icon></p> 
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="environments.length == 1"><h6 [ngClass]="isVisible">1/2</h6></div>
                <div *ngIf="environments.length == 2"><h6 [ngClass]="isVisible">2/2</h6></div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
        
        <div class="foldable-title">
            <p>Application</p>
        </div>
        <div class="foldable-content">
            <div (click)="toggleMenu()">
                <a class="foldable-text" href="">Overview</a><br>
            </div>
            
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Create new</a><br>
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Open</a>
        </div>
    
        <div class="foldable-title">
            <p>Business Process</p>
        </div>
        <div class="foldable-content">
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Overview</a><br>
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Create new</a><br>
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Open</a>
        </div>
    
        <div class="foldable-title">
            <p>Capability</p>
        </div>
        <div class="foldable-content">
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Overview</a><br>
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Create new</a><br>
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Open</a>
        </div>
    
        <div class="foldable-title">
            <p>Program & Project</p>
        </div>
        <div class="foldable-content">
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Overview</a><br>
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Create new</a><br>
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Open</a>
        </div>
    
        <div class="foldable-title">
            <p>Resource</p>
        </div>
        <div class="foldable-content">
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Overview</a><br>
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Create new</a><br>
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Open</a>
        </div>
    
        <div class="foldable-title">
            <p>Strategy</p>
        </div>
        <div class="foldable-content">
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Overview</a><br>
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Create new</a><br>
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Open</a>
        </div>
    
        <div class="foldable-title">
            <p>SWOT-analysis</p>
        </div>
        <div class="foldable-content">
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Overview</a><br>
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Create new</a><br>
            <a class="foldable-text" href="">Open</a>
        </div>
    <br>
    <app-collapse [@slideInOut]="menuState" ></app-collapse>
</div>


<div class="outside-navMenu">
    <div #editModal class="modal">
        <div class="card w40">
            <form [formGroup]="environmentForm" class="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="card-title">
              <p>Update your environment</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <br />
              <div class="card-input">
                <input formControlName="name" type="text" class="input w70" placeholder="Name" />
              </div>
              <br />
              <br />
              <button class="btn btn-primary-create" type="submit">save</button><br /><br />
            </div>
            </form>
            <div class="bar"></div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my navmenu-component.css

```
:host {
    margin-left: -400px; /* makes menu dissapear when collapsed */
    padding-left: 140px;
    color: #17313e;
    background-color: white;
    height:96.81%;
    width: 380px;
    position: fixed;
    border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0; 
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    bottom: 2em;
}


.foldable-title p {
    padding-top: 1em;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 18pt;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.foldable-content {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    padding-left: 2.5em;
    border-left: 2px solid #a4a4a4;
    height: 11.5%;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.foldable-text {
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #787878;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.foldable-text:hover{
    color: #56a5da;
}

  /* editbutton */
#dropbtn{
  float: right;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

#deleteButton{
    cursor: pointer; 
}

#editButton{
    cursor: pointer; 
}

a{
    color: #17313e;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: left;
}
ul {
    padding: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
ul :hover {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

#drop1{
    display: none;
}

.f-dropdown {
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: white;
    width: 60px;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }

/* dropdown */
.environmentHolder:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.environmentHolder{
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-env{
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 2em;
    background-color: rgb(243, 241, 241);
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #17313E;
}
.dropdown-env p{
    padding-top: 1.3%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-env-content{
    width: 220px;
    color: #17313E;
    background-color: rgb(243, 241, 241);
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    display: none;
    height: auto; 
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-env-content p:hover{
    background-color: rgb(223, 223, 223);
}

.dropdown-env-content p:nth-child(1){
    margin-top: 2%;
    padding-left: 5%;
}

.dropdown-env-content p{
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    padding-left: 5%;
}

fa-icon{
    color:#17313E;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
}

h6{
    color:#17313E;
    font-size: .7em;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 4.6%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.slidedown{
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
    animation-name: lineInserted;
    transition: height 0.3s;
}
.slidedown1env{
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
    animation-name: lineInserted1env;
    transition: height 0.3s;
}
.d-none{
    display: none;
}
.d-block{
    display: block;
}

/* Modal */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 9999; /* Sit on top */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-left: 25%;
    padding-top: 10em;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  }

  .outside-navmenu{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }
```

this is my navmenu-component.ts

```
import { NumberSymbol } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, OnInit, Renderer2, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, NgModel, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { faChevronDown, faPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { Capability } from 'src/app/services/capability/Capability';
import { Environment } from 'src/app/services/environments/Environment';
import { EnvironmentsService } from 'src/app/services/environments/environments.service';
import { Strategy } from 'src/app/services/strategy/strategy';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-menu',
  templateUrl: './nav-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-menu.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut',  [
      state('in', style({
        transform: 'translate3d(0,0,0)'
      })),
      state('out', style({
        transform: 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0)'
      })),
      transition('in => out', animate('300ms ease-in-out')),
      transition('out => in', animate('300ms ease-in-out')),
    ])
  ]
})

/**
 * @class
 * this class will create sliding behaviour for the nav menu
 */
export class NavMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('editModal', { static: false }) editModal: any;
  @ViewChild('ddl', { static: false }) ddl: any;

  filterModel!: NgModel;

  arrow = faChevronDown;
  plus = faPlus;

  textInvisible: boolean = true;

  environment!: Environment;
  newEnvironment: Environment
  environments: Environment[] = [];
  environmentForm: FormGroup;
  textDDL: String = 'Select Environment';

  private capabilities: Capability[] = [];
  envCapabilities: Capability[] = [];
  filteredCapabilities: Capability[] = [];

  strategy: Strategy;
  view: any;

  menuState:string = 'out';

  constructor(
    private el:ElementRef, 
    private renderer:Renderer2,
    private es: EnvironmentsService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private environmentService: EnvironmentsService
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEnvironments();
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm(){
    this.environmentForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['',Validators.required]
    })
  }

  updateEnvironment(){
    this.newEnvironment = new Environment(
      this.environmentForm.value.name
    )
    this.environmentService.updateEnvironment(this.environment.id, this.newEnvironment).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log(this.newEnvironment)
        this.router.navigate(['/'])
      }
    )
  }

  /**
   * @method
   * @returns this method will check if the form is valid, based on that it will either return an alert or call the update environment method
   */
  onSubmit(){
    if (!this.environmentForm.valid){
      alert("form not valid");  
      return 
    }
    this.updateEnvironment();
  }

  getEnvironments() {
    this.es.getAllEnvironments().subscribe((data) => {
      this.environments = data;
      console.log(this.environments);
    });
  }

  open() {
    this.ddl.nativeElement.style.display = 'block';
    this.isVisible(true);
  }

  close() {
    this.ddl.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
    this.isVisible(false);
  }

  openClose() {
    if (this.ddl.nativeElement.style.display == 'block') {
      this.ddl.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      this.ddl.nativeElement.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }

  changeDDLtext(name: String) {
    this.textDDL = name;
  }

  waitedText() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.textInvisible = true;
    }, 500);
  }

  isVisible(flag: boolean): string {
    if (flag) {
      return 'd-block';
    } else {
      return 'd-none';
    }
  }

  getEnvironment(id?: number) {
    this.environment = this.environments.filter((x) => x.id == id)[0];
    this.changeDDLtext(this.environment.name);
    console.log(this.environment);
    if(this.environment.strategy != null){
      this.strategy = this.environment.strategy
    }
    this.envCapabilities = this.capabilities.filter(x => x.environment.id == id);
    this.filteredCapabilities = this.envCapabilities;
    //console.log(this.envCapabilities)
  }

  goToEnv(){
    this.router.navigate(['/environment/create']);
  }

  goToEnvUpdate(id: number){
    this.getEnvironment(id);
    this.editModal.nativeElement.style.display = "block";
   // this.router.navigate(['/environment/update'], {state: {environment: this.environment}})
 }

 openMenu() {
  this.view = document.querySelector("#drop1")
  if(this.view.style.display === "none") {
    this.view.style.display = "block"
  } else {
    this.view.style.display = 'none'
  }
}

openDelete(id: any) {
  
}

closeDelete() {
  
}
  
  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick(target:any){
    let item = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('div');
  }

  toggleMenu(){
    this.menuState = this.menuState === 'out' ? 'in' : 'out';
  }

}
```

[here is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZFQU.png)

Comment: Please make sure .outside-navmenu{z-index:9999}

Comment: tried it, doesn't work. it has to be something with the :host thing i think but i don't know what to do with it

Comment: Just try to use it (!important). It may help.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to use the Angular CDK Portal. With the portal you can move data or component or template to a higher level on your application. At the higher level you can open for example the dialogue with the data which you have moved in. So you shouldn't have any z-index problems anymore.

Here is a example:

**app.component.html**

```
<h2>The portal outlet is below:</h2>
<div class="example-portal-outlet">
  <ng-template [cdkPortalOutlet]="selectedPortal"></ng-template>
</div>
<ng-template #templatePortalContent>Hello, this is a template portal</ng-template>

<button (click)="selectedPortal = componentPortal">Render component portal</button>
<button (click)="selectedPortal = templatePortal">Render template portal</button>
<button (click)="selectedPortal = domPortal">Render DOM portal</button>

<div #domPortalContent>Hello, this is a DOM portal</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {ComponentPortal, DomPortal, Portal, TemplatePortal} from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import {
 AfterViewInit,
 Component,
 TemplateRef,
 ViewChild,
 ViewContainerRef,
 ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';

/**
  * @title Portal overview
  */
@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-portal-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'cdk-portal-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-portal-overview-example.css'],
})
export class CdkPortalOverviewExample implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('templatePortalContent') templatePortalContent: TemplateRef<unknown>;
  @ViewChild('domPortalContent') domPortalContent: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  selectedPortal: Portal<any>;
  componentPortal: ComponentPortal<ComponentPortalExample>;
  templatePortal: TemplatePortal<any>;
  domPortal: DomPortal<any>;

  constructor(private _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.componentPortal = new ComponentPortal(ComponentPortalExample);
    this.templatePortal = new TemplatePortal(
    this.templatePortalContent,
    this._viewContainerRef
  );
  this.domPortal = new DomPortal(this.domPortalContent);
 }  
}

@Component({
  selector: 'component-portal-example',
  template: 'Hello, this is a component portal'
})
export class ComponentPortalExample { }
```